# Tensor Networks for Machine Learning, mnist classification

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, classification, tensor, mnist

I am dealing with a tensor network for ML task. Explicitly for classifying MNIST dataset of handwritten digits, each image consists of N = 28 × 28 = 784 pixels.

But the methodology and implementation is not so clear to me. So I need your help to correct my strategy if it is not suitable to solve such problems.

1. map the pixels p=(p1,p2,...pN) vector into a 2⁷⁸⁴ dimensional space with a mapping function, in my case I will use this function f(pi)=(pi, 1-pi).
   2.Convert this high dimensional array into a MPS. To get the MPS, we can use the SVD (Singular Value Decomposition), let's call it "T".
2. random initialization of an eighth tensor in the same form as T. Let's call it W.
3. the model function we will use for regression or classification is given by the contraction of the weight tensor W and the feature tensor T to return a scalar indicating whether a given input is in a class or not
4. define a loss function and optimize the weights to minimize this loss.

I'm still confused about how contraction works and how to implement it in Python from scratch (I don't want to contract with a built-in function).

In further steps, we need to add a dimension of size l (number of labels) to the weight tensor W.
The contraction that led to a scalar in the previous steps. Here it becomes a vector with ` entries between 0 and 1 and the highest entry corresponds to the label. I don't quite understand this and don't know what it means to add a dimension to a tensor and how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add dimension to tensor by `tensor.unsqueeze(1)`
for details and best understanding about Mnist calssification task
you can check this link
https://www.kaggle.com/code/justuser/mnist-with-pytorch-fully-connected-network
I hope this help you